# Adding & updating users from django admin to Auth0

Tags: python, django, authentication, authorization, auth0

I am trying to use Auth0 authentication in my django application. I am able to see the users added from auth0 in my django custom user table. Is it possible to add and update users from django application to Auth0. So far my code is mostly from the auth0 django tutorial.  Can we add users from django admin site with Abstract Base User model and show them in Auth0?
Below is code for authentcation that I am using. But is it possible to do 2-way? If I update a user in django admin site, it is not reflecting in Auth0 users. I couldn't get a clear picture of the AUth0 management API to update users from django side.. especially from admin site.

Any inputs would be of great help.

### auth0.py

```
class Auth0(BaseOAuth2):
    """Auth0 OAuth authentication backend"""
    name = 'auth0'
    SCOPE_SEPARATOR = ' '
    ACCESS_TOKEN_METHOD = 'POST'
    REDIRECT_STATE = False
    EXTRA_DATA = [
        ('email', 'email')
    ]

    def authorization_url(self):
        return 'https://' + self.setting('DOMAIN') + '/authorize'

    def access_token_url(self):
        return 'https://' + self.setting('DOMAIN') + '/oauth/token'

    def get_user_id(self, details, response):
        """Return current user id."""
        return details['user_id']

    def get_user_details(self, response):
        # Obtain JWT and the keys to validate the signature
        id_token = response.get('id_token')
        jwks = request.urlopen('https://' + self.setting('DOMAIN') + '/.well-known/jwks.json')
        issuer = 'https://' + self.setting('DOMAIN') + '/'
        audience = self.setting('KEY')  # CLIENT_ID
        payload = jwt.decode(id_token, jwks.read(), algorithms=['RS256'], audience=audience, issuer=issuer)

        return {'username': payload['nickname'],
                'user_id': payload['sub'],
                'email': payload['email']}
```

Comment: hey sk01 I have the same issue. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @MikeDHovhannisyan Not from Admin Site. I used DRF to add and update data to auth0.

Comment: Yeah me too, I ended up using Auth0 signup API.